# Find list of names in other Sheet and copy them

Tags: excel, vlookup

I’m asking for some advice on what is the best way to tackle this problem. Use any formulas inside excel or seek an alternative version (VBA Module)

In `sheet1`, I have 16 columns and around 200k rows.

In `Sheet2`, I have column 8 or H given with around 500 rows of data.

The goal is to look at column H name (which is unique) go to sheet1 find that unique name and fill in the column in sheet two.

I have tried using vlookup with no success until now. All I get is Na and I checked if the length is the same

```
=VLOOKUP(H2,todo,1,0)
=VLOOKUP(H2,All_Cells,1,0)
=VLOOKUP("Sheet4!",Sheet4!A40515:P40590,1,0)
```

Sheet1
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2
[image: Sheet2]

How it should look

[image: result]

**Edit after teylyn's answer:** I have implemented

```
=index(Sheet1!A:A,match($H2,Sheet1!$H:$H,0))
```

it seems to be working fine but in a  couple rows I get #N/A.
I have aligned them to the right and checked if they have the  same length using 
=len()  function.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that what you need is to fill the row on Sheet 2 according to the H column.

```
=VLOOKUP($H2,"Sheet1!A1:P40590,COLUMN(A1),0)
```

That formula will be for cell A2. You can copy and paste for the whole sheet.
(I am supossing that your range is A1:P40590. If it is not, then replace it)

Comment: This won't fly. VLookup does not look to the left, so you cannot return values from sheet 1, columns A to G.

Comment: Ups! You are right... I just try on the right section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Sheet2, cell A2. This is important. You must use this formula in column A, no other column!!

```
=index(Sheet1!A:A,match($H2,Sheet1!$H:$H,0))
```

Copy the formula to colums A to G and to columns I and further right. Note that without the $ signs in front of the `A:A`, the column reference will change to `B:B` in column B, `C:C` in column C and so on, whereas the references in the Match function are locked to column H with the $ signs.

Then copy the formulas down.

**Edit after comment:** You get `#N/A!` because the numbers are stored as text and I bet that in the lookup table they are stored as numbers. The left/right alignment in the cell does not matter. The value of the cell must be the same data type in both cases, so either make them both numbers or make them both text.

Comment: can you please check, I have added to my question. Your approach works really good besides around 4 rows. I have explained what's happening  above in my edited question. thank you

Comment: When Match (or Vlookup) returns `#N/A!`, that means that an exact match cannot be found. Check your data. Find the cell that you **think** is a match and let Excel compare with `=A1=B1`. Look for leading/trailing spaces, numbers stored as text.

Comment: what way would I change the data type of them. First look both of them look the same. How do I change both of them to numbers ?

Comment: Format the cell as **General**, then edit the cell and hit Enter. Or copy and paste the cells that are numbers (from your Sheet1) over the cells in Sheet2 that are text.

Comment: If I use vlookup how can I adjust it to show me blank instead of #N/A

Comment: That is a new question. Can you please mark this one as answered as explained in the [tour].

Comment: To show blanks instead of errors, you can wrap the formula into an IFError statement. The first parameter is the formula, the second parameter is what is returned if the formula throws an error `=IfError(Vlookup(bla,bla,bla,bla),"")`